# Mocking in Unit Tests for behavior. Why is verifying a method call beneficial?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking

I see lots of developers writing unit tests like this:

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void AddTrainer_InvokesProviderAddTrainer()
{
    //ARRANGE
    var trainerBusiness = new TrainersBusiness(_trainerProviderMock.Object);
    //ACT
    trainerBusiness.AddTrainer(new UserProfile());
    //ASSERT
    _trainerProviderMock.Verify(v => v.AddTrainer(It.IsAny<UserProfile>()), Times.Once);
}
```

I understand what is happening, I just don't quite what problem this intends to solve. Here the test is proving that the `AddTrainer` method in the business object is calling the `AddTrainer` method in the provider.

As long as the trainer is correctly added, what is the importance to me how the business method goes about doing it? To me this means if we decide we want to change the way the business method goes about adding a trainer in future, even though the trainer is still added, this unit test fails and we have to rewrite it.

It seems to me that this type of test is just confirming no one has changed your method, a bit like a checksum, rather than confirming anything useful with the behavior.

What am I missing?

Comment: @George: it's a question about a common practice which doesn't seem intuitive at first, I don't see why this should be closed.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel The content of the question isn't the problem; the issue is the way the question is written, "What's the point?" "Why do I care?" "Why should I give a monkeys how?"  It's leading into argumentation mode, instead of a 'problem that can be solved' mode.

Comment: Not to mention, of course, that there are lots of questions on Stack overflow about this: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mocking%20unit%20tests%20behavior%20site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: I changed the wording a little. It might have been off but the underlying question was "what does this verification tell me from a unit-testing perspective" which is a fair question to ask. If it's a duplicate then that's a good reason ofcourse but as it stands I think the question is answerable.

Comment: @George: I did search for previous questions but they seem to just assume testing the behavior is a good thing to do. I couldn't find why testing HOW something is achieved adds a benefit on top of testing that it HAS been achieved

Comment: @SimonN if you want a discussion about 'best practices' and is something 'good or bad' to do; you start to drift into opinion territory really fast (hence the close reason).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see this frequently in Unit Tests of void return methods because people don't know what to assert.  Sometimes it's a good idea and sometimes it is just to get high code coverage numbers.  I think the example you have falls under code coverage.  The key for me is the "It.IsAny" usage combined with the name of the test method.  The author could just have named it AddTrainer_GetCodeCoverage.  If you had 2 tests named AddTrainer_ValidTrainer_InvokesProviderAddTrainer and AddTrainer_InvalidTrainer_ThrowsSpecificExeception each making different checks on the Mock and confirming the values passed to the mock, you'd have something of value.

Comment: Thanks. That last sentence makes a lot of sense to me. I can see the benefit in testing that the correct route through the code is taken in different circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

This is to make sure that no one messes with the `TrainersBusiness.AddTrainer` method by adding some condition which would prevent `UserProfile` from adding into the `TrainerProvider`

Comment: But if they do mess with it and make the trainer get added some other way isn't that ok? Shouldn't the test here be that the trainer has been added, not how it has been added?

Comment: Imagine UserProfile has a property saying IsExternal, and if a requirement comes to prevent addition of a profile with this flag set to true if only added by a user who is not administrator, for administrators this should be allowed. Now if someone implements this logic to check IsExternal inside the method AddTrainer, it would be a mistake and it would be detectable by this test

Comment: Ah got you. So this test is helping enforce single responsibility for the method.